# MVC 5 asp.net Authentication on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

Hello I have this problem with my MVC 5 project.

I am trying to create a website in MVC 5 where the entire controller called "admin" needs to be authorized to be able to acces anything there.

It works just fine on hosted domains, but if I test it on localhost the Authentication is sort off "inactive".

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/Home/Login" />
```

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >

  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
```

```
    [Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // GET: Admin/Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
            if (bruger.ID > 0)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(bruger.ID.ToString(), true);
            Session["UserID"] = bruger.ID;
            Session["Level"] = bruger.Level;
            Session.Timeout = 120;
            @ViewBag.Loggedin = "Velkommen " + bruger.Navn;
        }
```

So the question is, how do I make the authentication work on localhost?

Comment: What is wrong? Are you logged in, what is not working?

Comment: Try incognito mode, maybe you are logged in...Otherwise, what is the error ?

Comment: The error is there is none! It authorizes me even if I am not logged in through my website when i host it locally. I want it to deny me acces unless I have logged in where I get